# Debug a WebPart Error in a SharePoint Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint, debugging, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I have a page layout that I use in my SharePoint solution when I programmatically create a new publishing page.  There is an error with one of the web parts that is included in the layout, so that when I am try and create the page, the operation fails.  Can anyone suggest a way of debugging the error with the web part?

Thanks, MagicAndi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could attach VS to the process running SharePoint.

[Here's some pointers](http://blog.developers.ie/cgreen/archive/2007/06/29/2767.aspx)

Comment: confusedGeek, accepted as answer.  However, this doesn't help for the case where the web part is failing on a production server and Visual Studio is not installed!

Comment: @MagicAndi, thanks sorry I don't really have a better suggestion for you.  The only other thought would be to stick a mess load of logging statements in the offending web part, this would let you narrow it down on production.  It's a crappy way to do it, but sometimes that's all you've got.

Answer (score 1):

I've had quite a few issues with that too. In my case, SharePoint Designer kept removing the leading / on the XSL file reference property of a Data View web part causing it to fail. Clearly a bug but very annoying.

What type of web part is causing the error? Can you create a page based on you page layout manually?